# How should I grow a money plant in a pot at home?

Tags: plant-health, soil, plant-care, containers

Two or three months ago I bought a money plant from a nearby nursery. It grew for some days but now it is still and no new leaves are coming, and some leaves have even wilted. I water the plant & do aeration but that doesn't seem to help.

It's placed outdoors, only for 10am-1pm (this winter), it will receive high sun for the rest of the day.

The day temperature these days is: 22°-25° Celsius (71°-77° Fahrenheit),
night temperature is 19°-21° Celsius (66°-69° Fahrenheit).

Please recommend good soil, manure & everything possible that can help.

[image]

Comment: Do you know which kind of moneyplant it is (there are a lot of species with the same nickname - is it Epipremnum Aureum ?).  Also, what is your watering regimine,  what is the drainage like and how exposed to sunlight is it?  (I'm no expert on vines, but I wonder if its been over watered)

Comment: I do not know which species is this , i can post photo of the leaf if that can help, however I have discovered it is too senstive to sunlight. if I pull these leaves out it in sun the leaves will welt thats why I have kept the leaves in shade

Comment: It doesn't like sun because it is a shade plant, good for indoors as well.  I really didn't know Pothos was considered Money Plant.  Learn something everyday.  Please tell us what you have been doing so we can nail this down.  This plant is one of the toughest plants in this world.  Is this outdoors?  Where do you live?  How cold does it get at night?

Comment: What do you mean by "do aeration"? Many plants do not like having their roots dug around on.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger  perforating the soil with small holes to allow air, water and nutrients to penetrate the roots. This helps the roots grow deeply and produce a stronger, more vigorous .The main reason for aerating is to alleviate soil compaction.

Comment: @Ciastopiekarz - not in pots, not a good idea, you'll just damage roots - aerating lawns is fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does look like a very poorly Epipremnum aureum (Pothos, Devil's Ivy). Agree with previous answer regarding using proper potting soil, and keeping it out of full, direct sunlight, although some sun in the mornings or late afternoon is fine. One thing though - why is there what appears to be a rusty trowel inserted into the pot? And I'm somewhat confused by your description of 'aerating' the plant, not sure what that means. If it means aerating the soil by disturbing it, don't, its not necessary and will be detrimental to the plant, and if it means moving it around so it gets more air, don't do that either - there's plenty of air everywhere and most plants kept indoors do not appreciate draughts.

The trowel should be removed, the plant turned out and repotted in proper potting compost, into a clean pot with drainage holes, watered thoroughly and allowed to drain down, then stood somewhere indoors where it gets reasonable light without being exposed to hot sun all day. Ongoing, water when the surface of the compost feels dry to the touch, and empty any outer tray or pot 30 minutes after watering so its not left sitting in water. Its probably sensible to cut back the long stem to promote new growth from the base of the plant too. Do not insert any random objects into the potting soil, it will interfere with the root system.

This plant can be grown outdoors if you have a suitable climate - it will not tolerate frost. Outdoors, once it's got used to it, partial sun is fine.

Comment: "pot with drainage holes" bears repeating. I usually end up with dirt soup when the pot has no drainage. Most roots do not like that.

Comment: Drainage means adding moisture and allowing excess to leave to allow air in the soil for the roots.  It is so amazing.  Now the only situation I've found that recuses drainage holes is Bonsai.  Very intimate relationship between root mass, soil mass and upper growth mass that most people don't understand.  To include daily watering, soaking...or close depending on the mass of roots, the upper growth and the volume of soil, kind of soil to boot.  Dirt soup is for water plants.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like the money plant I know.  Could be wrong.  Looks kinda like Pothos.  No matter.  Don't have to know the exact species to see a very unhappy plant.  See the leaves at the end of this...vine?  They are more 'juicy' than those closer to the roots.  Tells me that this plant has missed an important watering and is struggling to survive.  First off, I'd repot that guy in STERILIZED POTTING SOIL.  That looks like garden soil.  Get rid of any rock or gravel at the bottom of the soil that you thought would help drainage, actually causes the opposite, poor drainage.  Get rid of the lumpy stuff/bark on the surface so that you can see the soil.  (you have to get potting soil, seriously)...you've got drainage issues with fine textured garden soil (clay), possibly exacerbated by rocks or gravel at the bottom of the soil above the drainage hole causing a perched water table.  So possible root rot or just coming out of a drought that almost did it in.

Is the soil under the chunks of bark, garden soil?  If so, you need to repot using sterilized potting soil the stuff that comes in a bag.  Wash and sterilize the pot before replacing this plant.  If you've got rock at the bottom of the old soil, get rid of it before adding the fresh bagged potting soil.  Use panty hose or cheese cloth over the drainage hole to keep soil from washing out.  The stem is very healthy looking and if necessary we could help you propagate vegetatively.  You are using city tap water or too much fertilizer cause we see the salt deposits on top of your soil and the rim of your pot.  Tell us what you've been doing for fertilizer, what and how often, watering habits (what decides that your plant needs water).  Trying to diagnose using one photo is crazy.  It is a start!

Comment: i know the pot doesnt have drainage hole :(

Comment: Well, there is a reason we can be assured is causing this tougher than nails plant so much grief!  All plants need drainage.  Otherwise, the soil has little air and there are lots of fungus to cause root rot in this environment.  Is that potting soil or soil from your yard?  Dump all soil and plant, gently out, clean pot well, turn it over and drill an 1" diameter hole, carefully, slowly.  Fill with sterilized potting soil transplant this guy removing any browning or mushy roots and as much excess soil with out disturbing the glob of roots/soil.  Or go get another pot with a hole!  Critical!!

Comment: its not pot soil I am sure because i picked the pot from nursery very the seller picked soil from empty ground

Comment: @stormy: what is *your money plant*? *Lunaria sp.*?

Comment: Yes!  I have never heard Pothos called a money plant.  In all my years with clients asking about Money Plant...I always assumed Lunaria sp.  Have you?  Hey the only reason I am on here is to test what I know get feed back and learn more...keep learning more.  I love being corrected that is worth gold.

Comment: I took out soil out from the pot today and made a hole, checked drainage and put back soil.

Comment: Wait...what was the soil already in the pot?  Was that garden soil?  How old was this soil?  If you didn't use potting soil from a bag from the store you might not save this guy.  That hole will be a huge boon but using just any old garden soil, dirt from the yard is NEVER used for soil in pots.  And rotting roots or funky organisms could be a big problem with this old soil reinfecting  struggling healthy roots.  Just a sterilized potting soil the cheapest available is fine.  Garden soil is just wrong.  Making your own soil an adventure.  Pre-sterilized potting soil is just right.

Comment: Soil was not in the pot when i bought it he filled it from the ground, color of soil is reddish but of dark black . Its not potting soil, however I have received Perlite and vermiculite coming tomorrow . Can adding these two help to existing soil? If so how much quantity of it should I add to the pot

Comment: Oh poo.  Is there no way to purchase STERILIZED (heat treated to kill all things living to eliminate any bad guys because they would not have the natural controls normal garden soil would)...CRITICAL.  If you have gone to the trouble to purchase vermiculite/perlite get ready to put the whole mess to include the soil (if the vermiculite/perlite is in a bag it should already be sterilized) but any organics and soil have to be baked in your oven and cooled before using.   We've been running into this from people living in the big cities in India!  Unable to purchase bagged potting soil?! ?

Comment: I've just once made my own soil and regret doing so.  There are lots of bagged soils already sterilized.  Here is a link to make your own soil.  Better than just garden soil I guess.  Gotta sterilize the soil before adding...pretty stinky when you bake in your oven but will work better than that soil it is already planted in.https://themicrogardener.com/easy-diy-potting-mix-recipe/